# PowerShell: как проверить ввод адреса возврат для исправления

Tags: powershell

Вопрос заключается в том:
Нужен скрипт, который проверяет написания IP адрес и IP gateway-шаблоно(правильно указанно точек и указание чисел не больше чем положено 0-255). Если не верно указано возвращает на новый запрос ввода данных. 
И после, как все правильно написано подаёт пинг на ip адрес DC

Есть скринт по вводу данных

```
$Interface = Get-NetAdapter -Name *
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias $Interface.name -Dhcp Enabled
Remove-NetRoute -InterfaceAlias $Interface.name -AddressFamily IPv4 -Confirm:$false
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias $Interface.name -ResetServerAddresses
$IPAddress=Read-Host "Enter please IP-Address static"
$IPGateway=Read-Host "Enter please IP-Gateway"
$EthAdapters = Get-NetAdapter -Name *


foreach ($EthAdapter in $EthAdapters)

{
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $IPAddress -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $IPGateway -InterfaceAlias $EthAdapter.name
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses 192.1.110.111,192.1.110.155 -InterfaceAlias $EthAdapter.name
}

Wait-Event -Timeout 5
$hostname = $(hostname)
Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIpAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select InterfaceAlias,IPAddress,PrefixLength | out-gridview -title "IP Address $hostname"
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать встроенный в .NET парсер. Вот пример:

```
function Read-IpAddress
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [Object]$Prompt
    )

    while ($true)
    {
        [ipaddress]$ip = [ipaddress]::None
        $input = Read-Host $Prompt
        if ([ipaddress]::TryParse($input, [ref]$ip))
        {
            return $ip
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если можно полностью код, вствыляю в свой код с корекцией под свой код или ошибки и не выполняет проверку правильно...

Смог написать аналог...проверка на числа от системы 0-255 и не дает вписать другие символы, но принимает октет до 4

Пример:

принимает - 192.168.1.1 

принимает - 192.168.1

не принимает -192.168.1.е

не принимает -192.168.1.300